# How to extract the BSpline basis from scipy.interpolate.BSpline

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236221/how-to-get-the-spline-basis-used-by-scipy-interpolate-splev) I asked the community about how `scipy.interpolate.splev` calculates a spline basis.. My goal was to compute a spline faster then `splev` by pre-calculating a `bspline basis` and generate a curve by doing a `basis` to `control point` dot product.

Since then [a new `scipy.interpolate.BSpline` interpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html) was added to `scipy`. [It comes with a `basis_element` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.basis_element.html#scipy.interpolate.BSpline.basis_element), which I presume could be used to return the basis used to calculate a spline.

So for example using the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236221/how-to-get-the-spline-basis-used-by-scipy-interpolate-splev) with the inputs below:

```
import numpy as np

# Control points
cv = np.array([[ 50.,  25., 0.],
       [ 59.,  12., 0.],
       [ 50.,  10., 0.],
       [ 57.,   2., 0.],
       [ 40.,   4., 0.],
       [ 40.,   14., 0.]])

kv = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] # knot vector
n = 10  # 10 samples (keeping it simple)
degree = 3 # Curve degree
```

I can compute the following bspline basis:

```
[[ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.2962963   0.56481481  0.13271605  0.00617284  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.03703704  0.51851852  0.39506173  0.04938272  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.25        0.58333333  0.16666667  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.07407407  0.54938272  0.36728395  0.00925926  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.00925926  0.36728395  0.54938272  0.07407407  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.16666667  0.58333333  0.25        0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.04938272  0.39506173  0.51851852  0.03703704]
 [ 0.          0.          0.00617284  0.13271605  0.56481481  0.2962963 ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

Using `np.dot` with `basis` and `control points` returns 10 samples on curve:

```
[[ 50.          25.           0.        ]
 [ 55.12654321  15.52469136   0.        ]
 [ 55.01234568  11.19753086   0.        ]
 [ 53.41666667   9.16666667   0.        ]
 [ 53.14506173   7.15432099   0.        ]
 [ 53.1882716    5.17901235   0.        ]
 [ 51.58333333   3.83333333   0.        ]
 [ 47.20987654   3.87654321   0.        ]
 [ 42.31790123   6.7345679    0.        ]
 [ 40.          14.           0.        ]]
```

**Question** : is it possible to extract the basis as described above out of `scipy.interpolate.BSpline`?

Obviously I must be using it wrong, because when I try I get something like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline
b = BSpline.basis_element(kv)
print b(np.linspace(kv[0],kv[-1],n)) # i'm not sure what these values represent
[ 0.          0.00256299  0.04495618  0.16555213  0.28691315  0.28691315
  0.16555213  0.04495618  0.00256299  0.        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BSpline.basis_element` takes as its arguments the *internal* knots.

In your example, you padded the knots, and that did not do what you thought it would:

```
In [3]: t = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

In [4]: b = BSpline.basis_element(t)

In [5]: b.k
Out[5]: 8
```

So it's an 8th order spline.

If you wanted a quadratic spline, you would do

```
In [7]: b1 = BSpline.basis_element([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [8]: b1.k
Out[8]: 2

In [9]: b1.t
Out[9]: array([-1., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  4.])
```

Confused? The method is quite simple: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py#L243-L302

The callable returned by `BSpline.basis_element` is really a b-spline *function.* The result of calling it with an array argument is then equivalent to directly running the example code in the `BSpline` docstring in a loop for each element of your array, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html

EDIT: if you're after a variant of Cox-de Boor algorithm of calculating all non-zero splines at a given point, then you can look at a `_bspl.evaluate_all_bsplines` function, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/interpolate/_bspl.pyx#L161
(which itself is just a wrapper over a C routine which does all the heavy lifting; note that it's *hard* to beat that latter one performance wise.)

However, it's not a public function, so it's not guaranteed to be available in future versions. If you have a good use for it, and a suggestion for a user-facing API, bring the discussion over to the scipy bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I got confused by terminology.